# How to convert date integer keys into datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

after a lot of struggle, I cannot convert datekey (20200430) and timekey (103500) into proper datetime (2020-04-30 10:35:00). I do not have an option of joining on date dimension, the numbers must be converted using SQL functions.

What I've tried:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([datekey] AS DATE),1005) AS DATE_CONVERTED
--this is not yet datetime, but it could be start
```

Error I got was: Explicit int to date conversion is not allowed.

Then I tried this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, TimeKey, CAST(CAST(DateKey AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME))
```

This just produced wrong results. I am not sure why, but it is wrong. I just want to combine datekey and timekey into datetime. My format is YYYYMMDD and HHMMSS in integers. And I need datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server allows you to add together `datetime` values.  So, you can construct the `date` and `time` separately.  Here is one method:

```
select (convert(datetime, convert(varchar(255), date_key)) +
        convert(datetime, timefromparts(time_key / 10000, (time_key / 100) % 100, time_key % 100, 0, 0))
       ) as dt
from (values (20200430, 103500)) v(date_key, time_key);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7374e5f119237a6a4fa2333882b3d138) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon. I don't mean to devalue your answer, but isn't this very complex for such a simple requirement? I am not saying that this is not accurate or there is a simpler answer, I am new to SQL, and it seems to be a such a basic ask and I am finding it difficult to get to a datetime. Your answer works well, I am just surprised it took such a complex formula to get there.

Comment: @Julie1995 . . . If you have date/time keys, you should have reference tables that provide the information you want.  Actually parsing them seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I have 16 dates in my fact table, this would mean joining on date dimension 16 times though. This seems like a better solution than having 16 joins just to get the right format.

Comment: If you're still in the design phase, store your time key based on the seconds.  10:35 AM would be key value 38100 (seconds since midnight).  This performs very well and doesn't need joins to a time table to combine with a date.

Comment: The 16 joins shouldn't be a big deal.  Your date table should be quite small overall (short and skinny).  I've not had any problems with my date dimension/fact joins.  However, a large number of dates in a single fact may point to a problem with mixing grains in the fact table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the values into an unambiguoys format, and then convert. You can use `STUFF` to inject the needed `:` and `-` characters in:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CONCAT(datekey,'T',RIGHT('000000' + timekey,6)),14,0,':'),12,0,':'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-'),126)
FROM (VALUES(20200430,103500))V(datekey,timekey);
```